# SQL for finding invalid zipcode in address database

Tags: sql

I have a big address Oracle database with some invalid rows that I need to find.
There are streets that have old zip code so some streets have multiple zip code on the same street number.

I need to find all streets/steetnr with multiple zipcode.

```
City     | Street  |   nr | zipcode
New york   Main        3     10312
New york   Main        3     10313
New york   Main        3     10313
```

Comment: Please specify the rdbms which you are using

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve unique zipcode using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT city, street, zipcode 
from address_table 
GROUP BY zipcode 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT zipcode) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Having Count syntax

```
SELECT COUNT(nr), Street FROM StreetTbl
GROUP BY Street, nr HAVING COUNT(nr) > 1
```

Comment: I need to filter on Street and Street number some long street  have multiple zipcode

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of different zipcodes per street and get those with more than one using a `having` clause:

```
SELECT   city, street
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY city, street
HAVING   COUNT (DISTINCT zipcode) > 1
```

Comment: I need to filter on Street and Street number some long street  have multiple zipcode

Comment: @lars1595 please edit your question with the expected output - as the question is currently phrased, "I need to find all streets/steetnr with multiple zipcode." - which the query provides.